# cannot implicitly convert type 'system.datetime' top string c#

Tags: c#, alert

im trying to create a alert system and im getting this error: cannot implicitly convert type 'system.datetime' top string c#

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string dateInString = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString()); //error
        }
     DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInString);
     DateTime expiryDate = startDate.AddDays(30);

     if (DateTime.Now > expiryDate)
      {
         textBox3.Text = "O pagamento X expirou, faça o favor de pagar, caloteiro";
    }
    }
```

Help please.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, yes - you're declaring `dateInString` as a `string` variable, but you're assigning the result of calling `DateTime.Parse` to it. How did you expect that to work? Next you've got problems because it's out of scope when you use it a couple of lines later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the following line:

```
string dateInString = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
```

You're trying to assign a `DateTime` value into a `string` variable.

Instead, just take the value as is with a small `.ToString()` call on the object:

```
string dateInString = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

Apart from that, you've got some scope problem, you're actually refering to the last assigned `DateTime` value:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    string dateInString = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString()); //error
}
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInString);
```

Comment: Thank you, the error is gone, now i have another, can i ask you to take a look ? Nvm, its gone, Thanks again !

Comment: One thing, i have string Cells[3] on that line, what should i do in order all rows are read from the first till the last one ?

Comment: @DuarteAndrade If this solves your problem please mark as answered.